# $\ln(a+b)\leq\ln(a)+\ln(b)$

Tags: logarithms

Suppose $a,b>0$ are integers. Do we then have that
$$
\ln(a+b)\leq \ln(a)+\ln(b)?
$$

I think, since this is equivalent to $a+b\leq ab\Leftrightarrow 1\leq b-\frac{b}{a}$

it holds for $1<b<a$ only and, moroever, it is a strict inequality for these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. This indeed fails if $a=1$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$, as $\log(1)=0$, so the inequality becomes
$$\log(1+b)\leq\log(b)$$
which is clearly false. However, if we strengthen the premise to $a,b>1$, then this inequality holds.

Your strengthening to $1<b<a$ omits the equality case $a=b=2$, as
$$\log(2+2) = \log(2\cdot 2) = \log(2)+\log(2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. Then:

\begin{align}
\ln(a+b)\leq \ln(a)+\ln(b) \\
\\
(*)\quad \iff a+b \leq ab \quad\\
\\
\iff 1 \leq b - \frac{b}{a} = b\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right),\\
\\
\iff b \geq 2\ \text{ and }\ a \geq 2.
\end{align}

The $\impliedby$ at $(*)$ is justified by the fact that $\ln$ is an increasing function.
The $\implies$ at $(*)$ is justified by the fact that $\exp$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

$$a+b\le ab\iff 1\le(a-1)(b-1),$$ which is wrong for $a=1$ or $b=1$ and works for other naturals.